# How to close a blocked SSLSocket?

Tags: java, jsse

I have a Java server that needs an option to shut down all connections. As part of this, I'm calling close() on each client socket. The problem I'm having is that this call sometimes blocks indefinitely.

I can only reproduce this by simulating several hundred users, so its hard to pinpoint, but I suspect that this happens when that socket is blocked on a write.

I read in another question that calling shutdownOutput() on the socket helps, but it is not supported by SSLSocket (which I am using).

Is there a another way? 
Whether or not any data queued up for write gets sent is not important - I just need to kill the connection.

Comment: Maybe it helps to find out which threads/classes are in I/O on that socket, when you close?

Comment: @KristapsBaumanis I'm curious. Did my answer address your problem totally or partially? Thanks.

Comment: Mostly it just gave me insight on how SSLSocket works. My specific problem could be this (it only manifests when a lot of connections are being opened and one of them could easily choke on handshake and block everything), or it could be something else, but I will use this to avoid relying on that close() entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After extensive testing of my own application I might be able to shed some light on this. The phenomenon I was observing was the following:

When closing a *Java* `SSLSocket`, which was opened and is handled in `Thread` *A*, from a concurrent `Thread` *B*, the `close()` call sometimes blocks until the next `read()` in `Thread` *A*, which then retruns indicating `EOF`. Between the asynchronous call to `close()` in `Thread` *B* and any `read()` in `Thread` *A*, *A* can successfully perform `write()` operations on that socket.

I have now figured that this is only the case if `Thread` *B* performs the `close()` before the `startHandshake()` call initiated by `Thread` *A* has finished. After that, there seems to be no problem with closing the `SSLSocket` asynchronously.

This leaves us with the question how to solve the issue. Obviously, a bit of a state-based behaviour would help.

If one can live with a delay for the asynchronous `close()` in `Thread` *B*, calling `getSession()` before `close()` seems to work very well, because it makes *B* wait until *A* has the SSL session ready. However, this may cause a delay per socket, and also may lead to additional effort in case the `close()` does not get executed in `Thread` *B* before *A* starts to use the socket.

A better, yet less simplistic solution would be to work with two uni-directional flags. One (`handshakeDone`) would be used by *A* to indicate that the SSL handshake has been completed (there's no non-blocking API way for *B* to find this out). The other (`toBeClosed`) would be used by *B* to indicate that the socket is supposed to be closed.

*A* would check `toBeClosed` after the handshake has been performed. *B* would call `close()` if `handshakeDone` is false or set `toBeClosed` otherwise.

Note that for this to succeed, there need to be atomic blocks both in *A* and *B*. I'll leave the specific implementation (possibly optimized as compared to the algorithm described above) up to you.

There may be other situations where asynchronous `close()` calls on SSL sockets misbehave, though.